# Network days applied to different countries

Tags: networking, days

I have a formula for counting days in between dates. =MAX(0,NETWORKDAYS(C4+1,D4))
I was wondering if it is possible somehow in excel to change non-business dates (holidays) for different countries. In the US, the formula would skip over Labor day, but it would not skip over a holiday from another country. Is there a way to change this in Excel? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax of the `NETWORKDAYS`function is:

`NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date,holidays)`

You can use the third argument `holidays` to specify a list of holidays.

From the Microsoft Excel help:

Holidays   is an optional range of one or more dates to exclude from the working calendar, such as state and federal holidays and floating holidays. The list can be either a range of cells that contains the dates or an array constant.